# Trying to search backward first space or start of line

Tags: kill-text

I try to build a function to find the previous space or the start of line and kill the region from my current point to the found point.

(Edit) I will use it in LaTeX-mode.

**Example**: Let’s say I have the following content (`|` is my cursor)

`123 456 7/89|` I want to match `7/89`

`12/3|` I want to match `12/3`

At the moment I have the following

```
(kill-region (point) (save-excursion (skip-syntax-backward "^ ") (point)))
```

but it only matches spaces. I can’t find how to insert the "start of line".

Edit : behavior with multilines

At the moment, here is an example of match on multilines.

```
123 456 78/9
34/5|
```

matches `78/9\n34/5` and I would want to match only `34/5`.

Comment: AFAICT, what you have written works as you have described your requirement, so it is not clear what you want. How does the code you have posted fail to meet your requirements? BTW, syntax tables are mode-specific, so you should also specify in your question what mode the buffer is in.

Comment: `M-x describe-char` at an line end shows that line ends in `latex-mode` have syntax `>` (end comment). So you could replace `"^ "` with `"^> "`. I must admit that this looks very much like a hack.

Comment: Thank you : that’s perfect.
I didn’t though to look at an end line.